# Is there a Line of Bar Charting Javascript Library which is free/ Which contains the ability to add a report filter

Tags: charts, highcharts, report, rgraph

I've been looking for a javascript library like highcharts or rgraph which contains the ability to add a report filter. 
Does anyone know if there is one?

Comment: Isn't the usual approach to provide your own filtering, by refreshing the chart's underlying data set?

Comment: I have some charts with up to 80 people in the chart. You can imagine what this looks like on a line chart. I need the user to have the option to select a group

Comment: Right.  So you put the groups in a combo box on the page, and when the user selects the group, you redraw the chart using data filtered on that group.

Comment: [This looks interesting](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/).

Comment: This is nice, however, highcharts has a something very similar http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'report filtering' = show/hide certain data from the chart. Check this out. i haven't used it myself but looks good: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/

Also this one looks great too: http://nvd3.org - also powered by the awesome d3.js library

Comment: @JohnHenry I don't get it, why add the complexity of using yet another library when what you really want is just a javascript based selector of your current dataset and then just redraw the existing highchart.  Seems crazy to have the end-user load another library just to achieve that.